# Math behind normalization of features (fpfh)?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to get behind the math of how the features are normalized in [fpfh.hpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/features/include/pcl/features/impl/fpfh.hpp#L89-L100).

```
nr_bins_f1 * ((pfh_tuple[0] + M_PI) * d_pi_))
nr_bins_f2 * ((pfh_tuple[1] + 1.0) * 0.5))
nr_bins_f3 * ((pfh_tuple[2] + 1.0) * 0.5))
```

Why is `(pfh_tuple[]+M_PI) * d_pi_` or ...`+1.0)*0.5`?